# Find and clicking button with selenium without ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to click on a particular button on a webpage with Selenium in Python. How do I select and click on the button "Replace", with the following HTML?

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable no-close" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 300px; top: 411.009px; left: 692.001px; display: block;" aria-describedby="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span id="ui-id-5" class="ui-dialog-title">Search and replace</span>
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" class="title ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 62px; max-height: none; height: auto;">
        <div class="findReplaceText">Search for:</div>
        <input type="text" id="FindTerm" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all input-large">
        <br>
        <div class="findReplaceText">Replace with:</div> 
        <input type="text" id="ReplaceTerm" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all input-large"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
            <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Replace</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is another instance of a "Replace" button within the HTML which should be ignored:

```
<button type="button" class="titleButton replaceButton" id="riskFieldTemplateReplace">Replace</button>
```

Update:

Unsure if this is helpful. How the buttons HTML updates when hovering / clicking.

When hovering over the button:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Replace</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

When clicking the button:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover ui-state-focus ui-state-active" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Replace</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

When I run:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button']]").click()
```

I'm presented with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#205>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button']]").click()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 294, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 748, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 237, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//button[//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button']]"}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: You are providing only partial span class with `=` as `@class = 'ui-button'` means select span with exact match with class name `ui-button` which is wrong. It should be `@class = 'ui-button-text'` as my provided answer..try instead as `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']]").click()` or other option and let me know..

Comment: This gives a slightly different error `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`. While the option below gives : `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1103, 141). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>`

Comment: Ya that's good, it means you have got the element. now problem with click..

Comment: Is there any overlay element present when you going to click on replace button??

Comment: It appears as the error suggests the following is present `<div class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>` so yes.

Comment: Could you tell me when this overlay element getting invisible??

Comment: How do i work that out?

Comment: I'm just asking you when this overlay element getting visible and when invisible that's why I could give you proper solution..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `xpath` as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(.,'Replace')]").click()
```

Or if there is multiple button with same text `Replace` try as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[child::span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']]").click()
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']/parent::button").click()
```

**Edited** : If you are unable to `click` on element due to overlay of other element, you can try to `click` using `execute_script` as below :-

```
 replace = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']/parent::button");

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", replace);
```

Comment: I'm just getting the following: `>>> WebElement replace = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']../button")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with it highlighting `replace`

Comment: @difurious oops, updated with correct syntax...now try and let me know..:)

Comment: Same issue `>>> WebElement replace = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']/..")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Ah try with this `WebElement replace = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']/parent::button")` and let me know....see updated answer also..

Comment: Still same issue `>>> WebElement replace = driver.find_element_‌​by_xpath(".//span[tex‌​t() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']/pa‌​rent::button")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is there anything in particular i need to import?

Comment: The following worked `rep = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[text() = 'Replace' and @class = 'ui-button-text']/parent::button")` then `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", rep)`. So thanks for the help :D

Comment: @difurious Oh, I have got the mistake.. problem was not with the xpath, I have provided you Java syntax while you are using python...Sorry for stupid mistake...:)

Answer (score 1):

Try xpath:

```
//span[.='Replace']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def click_link(self, link_name: str):
    if link_name in self.driver.page_source:
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(link_name)
        elem.click()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.